# How to remove Sql Server Fingerprints?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a sql server which being monitor by Nagios. One day, i received some alerts from nagios come with some sensitive information like:

```
Critical Alert: dbi connect (Server name: ABC, Encrypted Password: 1, User: 
Sa.......)
```

How can i hide this ?